# Как ускорить асинхронную отправку запросов?

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
async def send_post(uid, session):
    async with session.get(f"https://cite.ru/{uid}") as resp:
        print(await resp.json())


async def main():
    sort_uid = ['6298b5d2259131164d5bc2d9', '6298b46b785e25431444371b', '6298b2e09778f61cff2256a3',
                '6298b2aa9c42436dc36aa8f6', '6298b456cc27fd234f147980', '6298b467ff886d01082592d3']
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*[send_post(uid, session) for uid in sort_uid])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Возможно его ускорить какими-то методами?

Comment: И если возможны какие-то доработки, то буду рад почитать идеи)

Answer (score 0):

Если бы мне нужно было как можно быстрее отправить какое-то кол-во запросов, я воспользовался бы многопоточностью, например ThreadPoolExecutor из библиотеки concurrent. Например:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests

def do_request(url):
    requests.get(url)

n = 10 #кол-во потоков
urls_list = ['some_url_1', 'some_url_2', 'some_url_3', <...>]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(n) as executor:
    executor.map(do_request, urls_list)
```

Прочесть подробнее можно здесь https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: Я пробовал потоки, но они оказались медленнее асинхронного парсинга)